# Спрятать/показать список анимацией, который распологается в строку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Что должно быть и как это реализовано на данный момент:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".rbm i").click(function () {
        var time = 300;
            var toggle = "hide";
            
            if ($(".L .hidden").css("display") == "none") {
                toggle = "show";
            } else {
                toggle = "hide";
            }
            $(".L .hidden").animate({
                width: toggle
            }, time);
    });
});
```

```css
.L {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.align {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.t {
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.L span {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: none;
}

.p0m0a {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.inline, li, ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

.rbm {
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
    font-size: 2.7em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.rb {
    max-height: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.rbm i {
    padding: 9px 18px;
    margin: 0 6px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t">
  <div class="rb align">
    <div class="submenu inline">
      <div class="L inline uC">
        <div class="hidden">
          <span>aa</span><!--
          --><span>bb</span><!--
          --><span>cc</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--
 --><div class="rbm inline">
    <i class="icon">DDD</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Т.к. все три значения связаны одним контекстом, то необходимо реализовать списком, который располагается в строку. Во время анимации элементы списка начинают скакать:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".rbm i").click(function () {
        var time = 300;
            var toggle = "hide";
            
            if ($(".L .hidden").css("display") == "none") {
                toggle = "show";
            } else {
                toggle = "hide";
            }
            $(".L .hidden").animate({
                width: toggle
            }, time);
    });
});
```

```css
.L {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.align {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.t {
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.L span {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: none;
}

.p0m0a {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.inline, li, ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

.rbm {
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
    font-size: 2.7em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.rb {
    max-height: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.rbm i {
    padding: 9px 18px;
    margin: 0 6px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t">
  <div class="rb align">
    <div class="submenu inline">
      <div class="L inline uC">
        <div class="hidden">
          <ul class="p0m0a">
            <li>ua</li>
            <li>en</li>
            <li>ru</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--
 --><div class="rbm inline">
    <i class="icon">DDD</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте код сюда, не только на jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.`
https://jsfiddle.net/2p4qsdgx/1/

Предлагаю поставить white-space: nowrap; для .p0m0a

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".rbm i").click(function () {
        var time = 300;
            var toggle = "hide";
            
            if ($(".L .hidden").css("display") == "none") {
                toggle = "show";
            } else {
                toggle = "hide";
            }
            $(".L .hidden").animate({
                width: toggle
            }, time);
    });
});
```

```css
.L {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.align {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.t {
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.L span {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: none;
}

.p0m0a {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.inline, li, ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

.rbm {
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
    font-size: 2.7em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.rb {
    max-height: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.rbm i {
    padding: 9px 18px;
    margin: 0 6px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t">
  <div class="rb align">
    <div class="submenu inline">
      <div class="L inline uC">
        <div class="hidden">
          <ul class="p0m0a">
            <li>ua</li>
            <li>en</li>
            <li>ru</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--
 --><div class="rbm inline">
    <i class="icon">DDD</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте код сюда, не только на jsfiddle.